# Managed DirectX downscaling sprites

Tags: sprite, scaling, managed-directx

I can't figure out how to downscale (make smaller) my sprites.

There are 2 functions that I use: **sprite.draw2d** and **sprite.draw**. When im using the first one, I specify the parameter "destination size", and when I use the second one, I apply the transformation to the sprite, for example "affineTransformation2D".

And everything goes well, until the width and height is less than 1 (original size). If size is (0.5, 0.5), then only upper-left quarter of the texture is drawn. If size is, for example, (0.7, 0.8), then MDX draws 2 identical textures with different sizes and semi-transparent on each other.

Why is this happening? Maybe there is other way to make sprites smaller?